# Glassfish: Weld won't inject from classes in one jar to classes in an adjacent jar in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6, cdi

I'm having trouble using dependency injection (with CDI/Weld) within libraries used in a war when deploying on Glassfish 3.1. I have two libraries, say:

```
WEB-INF/lib/library1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/library2.jar
```

library1 contains a public class, say "InjectMe". Library2 contains another public class, say "InjectionTarget" with an injection site like "@Inject public InjectMe injectMe;" .

Deployment fails with:

```
WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [InjectMe] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject packagename.InjectionTarget.injectionSite].
```

Both archives are valid CDI archives with a META-INF/beans.xml .

I've updated weld-osgi-bundle.jar in Glassfish 3.1 and still see the issue.

If I manually unpack library1 and library2, putting their classes directly into WEB-INF/classes, deployment succeeds and injection works as expected.

This is rapidly driving me completely insane. I'm on the verge of restructuring my modules so that the jar subpackages are unpacked with maven-dependency-plugin and archived as a merged jar that I then depend on from my war. That's pretty gruesome, though.

Ideas? Shouldn't this "just work"?

Comment: BTW, it appears to work correctly on Glassfish 3.2b6 so this may simply be (yet another) Glassfish CDI/Weld bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are running into this bug?

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-846

http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15721

http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15735

I think Glassfish 3.1.1-b04 and newer use Weld 1.1.1.Final which is marked as the fix version for the underlying Weld bug.  Testing with that exact version might be enough to confirm it.

Comment: You're quite right. I determined that about 4 hours after posting, but Stack Overflow wouldn't let me follow up until now.

Comment: I have Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (build 5), I have a web app with CDI managed beans that works fine on TomEE 1.5 SNAPSHOT, and it deploys just fine to Glassfish 3.1.2.2, but beans are not accessible at all. It would be nice to have this issue fixed; this issue drove me to TomEE.

Answer (score 4):

This turned out to be PEBKAC error. I'd updated weld-osgi-bundle.jar on my desktop and workstation but not laptop, but thought I'd updated it on the laptop too.

If you're reading this you probably have a similar issue. Check your weld-osgi-bundle version with:

```
asadmin list-modules | grep org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle
```

(Windows users: use findstr instead of grep, but the command is otherwise unchanged).

You should get the result:

```
Module : org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:1.1.1.Final
```

If you see an older version, update weld-osgi-bundle according to the instructions here:

```
http://seamframework.org/Seam3/CompatibilityHome#H-UpgradingWeldInGlassFish31
```

These instructions apply even if you don't use Seam. Weld 1.1.1 fixes several significant bugs in CDI. It's beyond me why a Glassfish 3.1.2 hasn't been released with it, because they're important fixes.